# Overriding Request timeout in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

HTTP requests to my app that take longer than >10m are being killed and I would like to override that behavior.

My YAML file looks as such:

`automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.90
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 5
  min_idle_instances: 0
  max_idle_instances: 1
  min_pending_latency: 15s
  max_pending_latency: 15s
  max_concurrent_requests: 50`

Is the proper configuration?
  `timeout: 20m`

Answer (score 0):

According with [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types), if you are in automatic scaling you can't handle requests longer than 10 minutes (1 minute for java 8, php5 and python2).

For longer requests, use basic or manual scaling but you have some trade-offs in configuration to take into account.